# How to keep validation but prevent form submit? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have few forms on my single page app. All forms use the same function for submitting data. In order to use HTML5 validation I had to change input type from `button` to `submit`. Now if I click on the `Submit` button I can see validation message but my form is still submitted. How I can prevent from submit and keep my validation? Here is example of my form:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Info</legend>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="frmst_lname" id="frmst_lname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters." required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="frmst_fname" id="frmst_fname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters." required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="dob">DOB:</label>
            <input type="text" name="frmst_dob" id="frmst_dob" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="datepick" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formItem">
            <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="frmstSubmit" value="Submit"></p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is example of my function for Submit button:

```
$('input[name="frmSubmit"]').on('click', function(){
   var formData = $('#'+frmID).serialize(); 
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'App.cfc?method=updateRecord',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj){
        //handle call back  
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
});
```

All form have same name for submit button. My JQuery selector use that name to submit the form. If anyone knows how I can keep the same logic/function that I already have and prevent from submit please let me know.

Comment: change input type from submit to button or add e.preventDefault() to prevent the form from submitting

Comment: if I change input type to button HTML5 validation won't work...

Comment: use the or part then to prevent submit

Comment: Also if I use e.preventDefault my function doesn't trigger ajax call or validation.

Answer (score 1):

You're using click for your event, which means your function will run on each click. Look into using the [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event instead. This should prevent the function from running until the form is submitted, which it can't do if there are HTML5 validation errors.
[EDIT] And for clarification, you would also change your event listener to be watching the form element, not the button. So:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function... etc.
```

Comment: That kind of solution does not work for me. I can't use form ID. There is more than one form in my app and this function is dynamic. I already applied some logic that relies to this type of function based on input name. Is there any other way to work around this?

Comment: You can set click handlers for each of your buttons to programmatically trigger a form submit. You would need to pass the form element being submitted, which means you could keep the form ID in a data tag on each button. That's what I would try off the top of my head.

Comment: This solution helped me even if I am using vanilla JS and not jQuery. Instead of having an handler on the click event of the submit button, I have an handler on the form and on the submit event. So, HTML validations are performed FIRST and if there are ok, then and only then the submit event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onSubmit property of form tag

```js
function submitForm()
{

  var formData = $('#'+frmID).serialize(); 
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'App.cfc?method=updateRecord',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj){
        //handle call back  
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onSubmit="submitForm();" method="POST" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Info</legend>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="frmst_lname" id="frmst_lname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters." required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="frmst_fname" id="frmst_fname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters." required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="dob">DOB:</label>
            <input type="text" name="frmst_dob" id="frmst_dob" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="datepick" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formItem">
            <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="frmstSubmit" value="Submit"></p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do like this

It would be better if you change input type to button because you are not submitting form you are sending ajax request.

First make different js script for validation and put the condition before calling ajax.

if(valid) call the ajax u calling already
if not return false

Comment: @Frsay Can you please provide as example? I have done something like that in the past but my validation was JavaScript. Now I'm trying to use HTML5 validation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first change ur input type to button
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  var fname = $('#frmst_lname').val();
  var lname = $('#frmst_fname').val();
  var dob = $('#frmst_dob').val();

  if(fname!='' && lanme!='' &&dob!='')
  {
   $('input[name="frmSubmit"]').on('click', function(){
    // call your ajax
   });
  }
});
</script>

Comment: I just found another problem with HTML5 Validation. I can enter white space in required field and validation will evaluate as true. This can cause all kind of problems.